Android Paging3 - How to auto-scroll to the end at startup and when new data is added
In my sample app I use Paging3 to show a list of students (by page), I want the RecyclerView to show the last page and auto-scroll-to-bottom. My setup is like this:
PagingSource:
class StudentPagingSource(
    private val studentDao: StudentDao
) : PagingSource<Int, Student>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Student> {
        val totalCount = studentDao.getStudentsCount()
        val initialPage = totalCount / params.loadSize    //<- the last page
        val page = params.key ?: initialPage

        return try {
            val students = studentDao.getPagedStudents(params.loadSize, page * params.loadSize)

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = students,
                prevKey = if (page == 0) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (students.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Student>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(it)

            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}

Repository:
class StudentRepository(
    database: StudentDatabase
) {
    companion object {
        const val PAGE_SIZE = 30
    }

    private val studentDao = database.studentDao

    fun getPagedStudents(): Flow<PagingData<Student>> {
        val pager = Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = PAGE_SIZE,
                enablePlaceholders = false,
                initialLoadSize = PAGE_SIZE
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { StudentPagingSource(studentDao) }
        )

        return pager.flow
    }

    suspend fun saveStudents(vararg student: Student) = studentDao.insert(*student)
}

ViewModel:
class FirstViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val studentRepository: StudentRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val uiScope = viewModelScope

    val students = studentRepository.getPagedStudents().cachedIn(uiScope)
}

Fragment:
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    studentAdapter = getStudentAdapter()

    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

    setupOptionsMenu()

    binding.recyclerView.adapter = studentAdapter

    viewModel.students.collectLatestOnStarted(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        studentAdapter.submitData(it)
    }

    return binding.root
}

Now the paging feature works fine, it loads and shows the last page at startup but not scrolling to the bottom, same as when new data is added.
So how can I make it scoll to bottom at startup and auto-scroll-to-bottom when new data is added?
